# Where do you put a method/s that will be use inside a model and controller in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960831/where-would-i-put-a-method-variable-that-will-be-used-in-my-models-views-control) but this ain't right a method in a config file? should I create another folder on the root level and name it shared methods?

Sample code that I need to put inside the controller and model.

```
def calc_exp_date(date)
 dif = (DateTime.now - date).to_i
 return dif >= 0 ? true : false
end
```

Comment: create Helpers?

Comment: Add a bit of code to your question.

Comment: @Xavier thought helpers are for views?

Comment: @SebastianPalma its really simple code. It will just calculate time. basically `DateTime.now - given_date`. I have to refactor some code.

Comment: You can always put it in a module. `Utils.calc_exp_date`. As for where to put it, in my projects it normally goes into `app/lib`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yea I was just reading about it. thanks man.